# How cant I show changed label image in iupLua?

Tags: lua, luabind

When I change image attribute of label after, but image can't show. When I double Click list to change label image ,but no respond, image do not show. Why?

```
require "iuplua"
require "iupluaim"
list = iup.list{"flag", "cut", "undo"; expand = "no"}
image = nil
box = nil
label = iup.label{active = "yes", visited = "true"}
function list:dblclick_cb(i, str)
    image = iup.LoadImage(str .. ".PNG")
    label.image = image
end
box = iup.vbox{list, label}
dlg = iup.dialog{box; title = "Lists", size = "400x100"}
dlg.show(dlg)
iup.MainLoop()
```

Comment: did you debug with a lua debugger? is your code even called? are you getting any errors/exceptions?

Comment: I’m use Editplus configing lua for windows to run my code in win 7, I'm not use breakpoint, only use runtime info to debugging my code.